# Vagrant 1.9.4 stuck at Mounting NFS shared folders

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I know there has been a lot of questions about this but take a time and look into this, its not like the others.

I'm using Vagrant 1.9.4 and Virtual box 5.1.18. When I do vagrant up, it gets stuck at  Mounting NFS shared folders.. I did vagrant debug and had this log message

```html
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
 INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
 INFO ssh: Execute:  (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
 INFO ssh: Execute:  (sudo=false)
 INFO guest: Execute capability: mount_nfs_folder [#<Vagrant::Machine: default (VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider)>, "10.20.48.1", {"/var/www/html/clearcare/current"=>{:nfs=>{:mount_options=>["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]}, :guestpath=>"/var/www/html/clearcare/current", :hostpath=>"/var/www/vhosts/clearcare", :disabled=>false, :type=>:nfs, :__vagrantfile=>true, :map_uid=>1000, :map_gid=>1000, :nfs_udp=>true, :nfs_version=>3, :uuid=>"3945067650", :linux__nfs_options=>["rw", "no_subtree_check", "all_squash", "anonuid=1000", "anongid=1000", "fsid=3945067650"]}, "/var/www/html/laraclear/current"=>{:nfs=>{:mount_options=>["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]}, :guestpath=>"/var/www/html/laraclear/current", :hostpath=>"/var/www/vhosts/clearcare", :disabled=>false, :type=>:nfs, :__vagrantfile=>true, :map_uid=>1000, :map_gid=>1000, :nfs_udp=>true, :nfs_version=>3, :uuid=>"3945067650", :linux__nfs_options=>["rw", "no_subtree_check", "all_squash", "anonuid=1000", "anongid=1000", "fsid=3945067650"]}}] (redhat)
 INFO ssh: Execute: mkdir -p /var/www/html/clearcare/current (sudo=true)
 INFO ssh: Execute: echo; printf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK remotely: /tmp/ssh-oEprVv1512/agent.1512
 INFO ssh: Execute: mount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current (sudo=true)
 INFO ssh: Execute: echo; printf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK remotely: /tmp/ssh-oEprVv1512/agent.1512
 INFO retryable: Retryable exception raised: #<Vagrant::Errors::NFSMountFailed: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
>
 INFO ssh: Execute: mount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current (sudo=true)
 INFO ssh: Execute: echo; printf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK (sudo=false)
 INFO ssh: Setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK remotely: /tmp/ssh-oEprVv1512/agent.1512
```

After a while I had this error message too

```html
Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

ERROR vagrant: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:240:in `execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:250:in `sudo'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/nfs.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in mount_nfs_folder'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/nfs.rb:36:in `block in mount_nfs_folder'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/nfs.rb:17:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/nfs.rb:17:in `mount_nfs_folder'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:43:in `capability'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/synced_folder.rb:108:in `enable'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:93:in `block in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:90:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:90:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:25:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:49:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:36:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 INFO interface: error: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::NFSMountFailed", "The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.\nVagrant assumes that this means the command failed!\n\nmount -o vers=3,udp 10.20.48.1:/var/www/vhosts/clearcare /var/www/html/clearcare/current\n\nStdout from the command:\n\n\n\nStderr from the command:\n\nmount.nfs: Connection timed out\n"]
```

Comment: do you have nfs installed on you host ?

Comment: Yeah, don't worry I fixed it myself

Comment: @GideonAppoh how did you fix it?

Comment: I don't know if it will work for you but I downgraded the nfs-utils I had on fedora to the immediate previous version and everything started working fine.